# How do I get Advanced Cocktail Crafting?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I keep getting coconut shells and magical ice cubes and little paper umbrellas when I raid the bar in the Ice Hotel. From the wiki, it looks like I need Advanced Cocktailcrafting to even use those things, and I am not entirely sure if I can do that as a Turtle Tamer. I have a Bartender in the Box at my campsite, if I need it.

How do get Advanced Cocktailcrafting? Failing that, is there another way to use those things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Advanced Cocktailcrafting](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Advanced_Cocktailcrafting) is a [Disco Bandit](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Disco_Bandit) skill, so it's not available to you as a Turtle Tamer. It is anyway one of the most useful skills you can find in the game, giving you access to some of the best quality cocktails easily available.

If you've started Ascending to perm some skills, consider doing a Disco Bandit run just to get Advanced Cocktailcrafting, it will help you greatly in subsequent runs (especially in Hardcore), getting you much needed adventures and stats; just remember that Coconut Shells let you create Muscle cocktails, Paper Umbrellas are for Misticality cocktails and the Ice Cubes are for Moxie.

The only other use for your cocktail garnishes is as equipment, but if you've just reincarnated you'll surely find better weapons and armors in a few adventures, while later, at higher levels, you'll definitely have better equipment available.